# Outlook VSTO Add-In using a Form and Button - Forward Email Won't Display and Can't get Button on Home Ribbon

Tags: vb.net, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm new to creating Add-In's for Outlook, but have managed to crash and bash my way through most of what I'm trying to do.  I have been trying in C# as most examples and documentation use C#, however I'm not that comfortable writing in C#.  I have used VBA quite a lot in the past so VB.Net is easier for me to use.

So far my Add-In does the following:

1. Adds a button when reading an email (OfficeID set to TabReadMessage).
2. When you click the button a form is displayed which asks for some information.
3. There's a button on the form to continue which validates the form and identifies the current MailItem.
4. Using the current MailItem, it appends some text and then attempts to Forward the email with the revised text.

Where I'm stuck is with the Forward() function.  I can update the To and Subject, but I can't Display() it.

I think I'm ok up to here

```
    ' Create an application object which is needed to get to the ActiveInspector
    Dim application As Outlook.Application '
    application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application

    ' Variables to inspector, needed to get the current item, current mail item, the forward email (so we can update the subject)
    Dim mailItem As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem
    Dim forwardMailItem As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oInspector As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector
    Dim currentSubject As String
    Dim forwardSubject As String

    oInspector = application.ActiveInspector
    mailItem = oInspector.CurrentItem
    ' forward email gets created here
    forwardMailItem = mailItem.Forward()

    currentSubject = mailItem.Subject
    forwardSubject = "some other stuff added - " & currentSubject
```

If I do a MsgBox at this point and reference **forwardMailItem.Subject**, the new MailItem must be there as it displays the revised subject.

Once I add the following line, it's like the MailItem object has gone - ie if I do MsgBox(forwardMailItem.Subject) nothing happens.

```
forwardMailItem.Display()
```

If I remove the above line and just put the following, the email gets sent.

```
forwardMailItem.Send()
```

Part 1 - I can't get the forwardMailItem to display and don't understand why?

Part 2 - I don't know how to get the new Ribbon I created to also show when on the Home Ribbon.  I found how to change the OfficeID to show it on TabReadMessage instead of the default TabAddIn, but don't know what to search for to find how to add it to the Home Ribbon.

Comment: What do you mean by " it's like the MailItem object has gone" - do you mean no message is being displayed?

Comment: I just updated the details with "ie if I do MsgBox(forwardMailItem.Subject) nothing happens."  Prior to invoking the Foward() function this displayed the subject.

Comment: Do you have "on error resume next" anywhere in your code by any chance?

Comment: No, I hadn't included any error handling as yet.  Weird thing is, I added On Error GoTo forwardError and then put the forwardError label and MsgBox with Err.Number.  I rebuilt the project and this time it displayed the new email.  I have since removed the error handling and the email is not being displayed.  This looks to maybe be a glitch in the project or something?

Comment: I have basically the same code in a C# project and it won't Display the email.  I haven't tried adding error handling to that project.

Comment: Try `Display(true)` - does it make a difference?

Comment: Unfortunately, no adding `Display(true)` didn't help.  I did a basic try/catch and it looks like there is an error, but I couldn't catch the actual error.  Out of my depth with the reason.  I went back to the VB.Net project and that's still working.  I might have to stick with that one. No idea why the VB.Net started working.

Comment: Actually found out why I couldn't catch the error.  The error is "Outlook can't do this because a dialog box is open.  Please close it and try again".  I'm still displaying the form, but nothing else is on screen.